# voltage follower design question

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback

[image: Simple voltage follower]

Hi , I am trying to build a simple voltage follower circuit in IC. I have tried to build ideal Op-Amp as a transconductor. Now, it requires minimum bias voltage for it to operate as a transcondcutor (lets assume it to be single stage NMOS input diff amp). What if I want a voltage level lower than the threshold voltage. Then it should be based on PMOS design? I am trying to design offset correction for the transconductor using Auto zeroing technique. Suppose, I try to model offset around 10mv, how should I model it along with input bias requirement? What will be the output voltage for such a small value. Is it better to go for differential design as it holds difference in voltage level. Is it possible to make voltage follower which has level of 10mv possible in NMOS based system?

Comment: Please state the output swing requirements of your buffer. Do you simply need it to work between 0-500mV (to put a value to the threshold voltage of the mos)?

Comment: I am trying to work on auto zero offset correction. I was wondering whether offset would be added with the vbias of input pair transistor. for eg, if vbias =500mv and offset is 10mv, will it be added with bias voltage? By my understanding it should be added .

Comment: what is vbias exactly? the input to your differential pair?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for lower input voltages, nmos input pair can't work. You will have to use pmos input pair.
To model offset, add a voltage source in series with one of the nmos input pair transistor's gate.
Since you will use it as a unity gain follower, output will be input+offset or input-offset depending on which direction you add the offset.
Fully differential design will improve power supply rejection but impact of offset won't change.
You can't make nmos input pair with a level of 10mV as long as the nmos has positive vth